# Не работает фильтр в Select2 в модальном окне Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, select2

При использовании select2 в модальном окне Bootstrap не работает фильтр, будто он отключен.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".js-example-basic-single").select2();
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Launch demo modal</button>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <select class="js-example-basic-single">
          <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
          <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Вариант 1 (правим HTML модального)**

Из кода модального окна убираем `tabindex="-1"` *PROFIT!*

**Вариант 2 (вносим изменения через JS)**

`$.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = function() {};` *PROFIT!*

**Вариант 3 (поднимаем z-index в css select2)**

```
.select2-close-mask{
    z-index: 2099;
}
.select2-dropdown{
    z-index: 3051;
}
```

Обычно модальное окно находится на уровне `z-index:1000`, поэтому поднимаем z-index для select2 и *PROFIT!*

P.S: Это краткий перевод ответов участников SO по вопросу [Select2 doesn't work when embedded in a bootstrap modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18487056/select2-doesnt-work-when-embedded-in-a-bootstrap-modal). Подробные описания ответов можно найти по ссылке на оригинальный вопрос.